# EF Code First selecting rows based on many to many relationship

Tags: linq, ef-code-first

I have the following code in my repository:

```
public PagedResult<Post> GetAllPublishedByTag(int tagId, int start, int max)
{
    var query = Database.Set<Post>().Where(p => p.IsPublished)
                                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                                    .Skip(start)
                                    .Take(max);

    int total = query.Count();
    var result = query.ToList();

    return new PagedResult<Post>(result, total);
}
```

This will give me all published posts. But what I want is selecting all published posts for a certain tag. My model is setup in such a way that tags have a many to many relationship to posts. I tried to slightly modify the above code but this did not work:

```
public PagedResult<Post> GetAllPublishedByTag(Tag tag, int start, int max)
{
    var query = Database.Set<Post>().Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(tag) && p.IsPublished)
                                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                                    .Skip(start)
                                    .Take(max);

    int total = query.Count();
    var result = query.ToList();

    return new PagedResult<Post>(result, total);
}
```

I would prefer to pass in the tagId (as per the first code example) as opposed to the tag object but not sure how to correctly write the LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = Database.Set<Post>().Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tagId) && p.IsPublished)
.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
.Skip(start)
.Take(max);
```

Side Note: I believe you may have issues with your pagination, as the variable total is calculated after skip/take are called.